# OpenCL mandlebrot plot, very noisy on GPU

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu

In an attempt learn OpenCL I decided to make a plot of the Mandlebrot set.
It seems to work fine, on the CPU that is. The two images below shows, first the kernel executed on the CPU (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz), and the second image shows the image when rendered on the GPU (HD Graphics 4000).

This is the kernel:

```
typedef float2 Complex;

Complex complex_mul(Complex a, Complex b) 
{
    return (Complex)(a.s0*b.s0-a.s1*b.s1, a.s1*b.s0+a.s0*b.s1);
}

__kernel 
void mandelbrot (__global float* p)
{
    const int x = get_global_id (0);
    const int y = get_global_id (1);
    const int arrlen = PIXELS_WIDTH * PIXELS_HEIGHT;


    float width = PIXELS_WIDTH;
    float height = PIXELS_HEIGHT;

    float whRatio = width / height;

    float tx = x;
    float ty = y;

    float px = ((tx / float(PIXELS_WIDTH)) - 0.5) * 2.0;
    float py = ((ty / float(PIXELS_HEIGHT)) - 0.5) * 2.0 / whRatio;

    Complex z;
    z.s0 = 0;
    z.s1 = 0;
    Complex c;
    c.s0 = px;
    c.s1 = py;


    float color = 0.0;

    int iterations = 500;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        z = complex_mul(z,z) + c;

        if ( length(z) > 2.0)
        {
            float u,o;
            u = i;
            o = iterations;
            color = ( u / o );
            break;
        }
    }


    const int pId =  y * PIXELS_WIDTH + x;
    if ( pId < arrlen )
    {
        p[ pId ] = color;
    }
}
```

And the host program... at least the interesting bit (I hope):

```
size_t globalSizes[2] = { PIXEL_WIDTH, PIXEL_HEIGHT };

cl_mem image_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(image_data), NULL, &error);
CheckError(error);

error = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &image_buffer);
CheckError(error);

error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalSizes, NULL, 0, NULL, &computeDone); 
CheckError(error);

clWaitForEvents(1, &computeDone);

error = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, image_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(image_data), image_data, 0, NULL, NULL);
CheckError(error);

clReleaseMemObject(image_buffer);
```

I run this on a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.9.5. The noisy part around the set changes slightly (randomly) for each execution.

I hope that I've supplied enough information, and if anyone have a suggestion on what might be wrong, I'll be glad to hear!

Thanks : )

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

I did the following:

change all number literals to floats as suggested by huseyin tugrul buyukisik in the comment.

Then changed `length(z) > 2.0` to `(z.s0 * z.s0) + (z.s1 * z.s1) > 4.0f`

and then tried to play around with the iteration counter.

It seems that the noise is very sensitive to the iteration number.

For example, 1000 iterations generates very much noise, yet 1009 iterations makes a very smooth image. Any suggestions on why this happens?

Cheers

Comment: İntegrated gpu doesnt support double precision. Please try 5.0f instead of 5.0 and 2.0f instead of 2.0

Comment: Hmmmm.. tried that. but it has no effect : /

Comment: Any NaNs in output array?

Comment: Just made a check, no NaN's. However, I get numbers that exceed 1 (examples are 1.8 and 2.7), which is strange as it should strictly be between 0 and 1?

Comment: Yep, this is by all means wrong. On the CPU i get all numbers strictly in [0;1] but on GPU they seem to range from -4 to 4...

Comment: Can you try without any float2 float4, .. Sometimes drivers can be problematic with them. My fx8150 had some problems using float16.

Comment: That did the trick! care to make it as an answer, then I'll mark it at the accepted answer.

Comment: You have to bear in mind precision of GPUs is typically 32bits precision. Even in double, the precision is not great. CPUs operate on 48bit precision even when working with 32 bits. Mandlebrot generator works with super low values and you can see artifacts when dividing such small numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes drivers have bugs on implementations of vectors on driver side. Trying a "scalar" version simply solves it if fp64 support or host-side element alignment checking doesn't do anything.

For example, my fx-8150 cpu had issues with float8 and float16 but gpus were ok with any native vector and there were no issues with fx-8150 in the distant past. Maybe we are forced(accidentally or knowingly) to buy new tech.

You should try different versions of drivers since sometimes corporations deliberately or accidentally tweak settings and corrupt support lists.

Maybe I'm wrong and your integrated gpu is dying.

Answer (score 0):

Code works well with minor modifications (e.g. (float)(PIXEL_WIDTH) and 0.5f, etc.) on Windows 8.1 on the GPU using the latest driver for your type of processor, so this suggests a graphics driver issue on Mac.

Comment: Yeah, I think the apple drivers are a little rusty. I read about others having issues with os x and opencl.